# BING searchWeb API OR operator

Tags: bing-api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795643.aspx

> OR: Finds webpages that contain either the term that precedes the
>   operator or the term that follows the operator. Same as | and ||.

So, the query `a b c OR d e` will return results for `a b c e` and `a b d e`, right?

**How can I find results for `a b c` and `d e`?**

I tried with `(a b c) OR (d e)`, but it does not work. The parenthesis are used for something else:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795621.aspx

> In combination with ), operator for term separation and precedence.
>   Examples As Operator: foo(bar)blue

I could use `"a b c" OR "d e"`, but then "a b c" should be exact query, which I do not want:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795609.aspx

```
"phrase”: Returns results that contain the specified phrase, exactly.
```

**How can I find results for `a b c` and `d e`?**

of course, I could make 2 separated API queries, but we pay twice for that.

Comment: according to this other page, we can use parenthesis, such as `(foo AND bar) | (bing AND yahoo)`, so this solves the problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795639.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this other page, we can use parenthesis, such as `(foo & bar) | (bing & yahoo)`, so this solves the problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795639.aspx

`(a b c) | (d e)`

Answer (score 0):

Combining multiple queries is typically not a good practice because relevance for such queries becomes very, very difficult. With multiple words in each string and various emphasis (weights) on different words, it becomes difficult to parse what is expected for search engines. You can see this non-optimal behavior across multiple search engines.

If you are okay with uncertain results, +a b c OR +d e on Bing may be okay for you. Note that this is not perfect in any way but closest to what you can get.

Comment: `+` means to give more importance to this word, right? so how does this query be "closest to what i can get"?

Comment: It's more about the syntax that works for "OR" operator. + is meant for phrase match.

Comment: It will preserve your phrases such as "a b c". I think this is what you are trying to do. "Phrase 1" OR "Phrase 2". If not, this won't help.

Comment: I don't see the `+` in the Bing SearchWeb reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795620.aspx
 I do see `"phrase"` for phrase match. any way, if by `+a b c OR +d e` you meant `"a b c" OR "d e"`, I already mentioned in the question that this option was not useful for my case.

Comment: in any case, I also already commented in the question that I solved the question: according to this other page, we can use parenthesis, such as `(foo AND bar) | (bing AND yahoo)`, so this solves the problem. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795639.aspx